# How to detect a zip bomb using PHP?

Tags: php, zip

I’m making a PHP script that retrieve user-given zip files, unzip it, and do some stuff with the files in it, using a `ZipArchive` object. How can I avoid zip bombs like [42.zip](http://www.unforgettable.dk)?

Comment: By using a virus scanner on the files uploaded before you accept them.

Comment: couldn't you just unzip the top level?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helped, OP.

Comment: @MatthewBlancarte: Well with the zip in question it does not.

Comment: @hakre: Provided that the virus scanner is not itself vulnerable to ZIP bombs. That's just adding a complexity level without actually solving the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out zip_entry_filesize: http://php.net/manual/en/function.zip-entry-filesize.php

It should give you the actual size of the uncompressed archive within the .zip file. Here's an example function provided in a comment on the manual page:

```
function get_zip_originalsize($filename) {
    $size = 0;
    $resource = zip_open($filename);
    while ($dir_resource = zip_read($resource)) {
        $size += zip_entry_filesize($dir_resource);
    }
    zip_close($resource);

    return $size;
}

$size = get_zip_originalsize('file.zip');
echo "original size: $size bytes\n";
```

Comment: I filled a `bomb` file with 2.4M of zeros, I compressed it into a `bomb.zip` file (2.4K), I copied it four times, and then I compressed the five zip files into a `file.zip` (14K). The function gives me an original size of 12985 bytes, which is the size of the five zip files, not the whole size.

Comment: Actually, my PHP script doesn’t need to recursively unzip files, so in fact it’s ok if the user submit a zip bomb, it will delete the nested zip archives, but I’m interested in a solution to have the whole size.

Comment: Been looking into this myself and whilst the function above does return the size of files I have zipped up multiple times. In the case of `42.zip` the size is returned as `0`. I believe this is due to the password protection.

Comment: Also this only checks the top level. For zips within zips it needs to be recursive.

Comment: This answer is outdated for PHP8.